# IMAP4.search returns all the email instead of those from one sender

Tags: python, email, imaplib

I want to search all the emails from a **specific** address.And I used imaplib.Here is my simple code:

```
import imaplib

mail = imaplib.IMAP4("imap.qq.com")
mail.login("2781936169@qq.com", "outgrcjehevvdfbi")
mail.select() 
result, data = mail.search(None, "(FROM '18217099317@163.com')")
print(data)
```

But it returns **all the emails** in my box which seems my search criterion doesn't work.
It returns the same when I code like this:

```
result, data = mail.search(None, "ALL")
```

So I wonder why.There is no error message, by the way.But the result's just wrong.

Comment: My guess would be that qq's IMAP server doesn't actually implement IMAP search properly.  In the past, QQ was very not clliant with standards, and implemented just enough to get a typical sync everything client working.

Comment: Thank you so much.It's a pity if it wont't work!

Comment: *compliant.  Phone keyboard ate a few keys!